# Docker application not able to connect to database

Tags: java, spring-boot, docker, docker-compose, mariadb

Issue detail:

I have a docker-compose file with 1 MariaDb database and 1 simple SpringBoot application which connects to the database.

The docker-compose.yml file:

```
version: '3.9'
volumes:
  out:
    driver: local

services:

  users:
    image: <MY_HOST>/users:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT
    container_name: users
    environment:
      spring.datasource.url: jdbc:mariadb://users-db:3306/users
    ports:
      - "9003:9003"
    depends_on:
      - users-db
    networks:
      - my-network

  users-db:
    image: mariadb:10.6.4
    restart: always
    container_name: users-db
    environment:
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: admin
      MYSQL_DATABASE: users
      MYSQL_USER: testuser
      MYSQL_PASSWORD: test
    ports:
      - "3306:3306"
    command: --default-authentication-plugin=mysql_native_password
    networks:
      - my-network
    volumes:
      - ./out/users_db:/var/lib/mysql

networks:
  my-network:
    driver: bridge
```

In my SpringBoot application.properties file (users server name in docker-compose.yml) i have the following content:

```
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:mariadb://localhost:3306/users
spring.datasource.driver-class-name=org.mariadb.jdbc.Driver
spring.datasource.username=testuser
spring.datasource.password=test
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=validate
spring.jpa.hibernate.naming.physical-strategy=org.hibernate.boot.model.naming.PhysicalNamingStrategyStandardImpl
spring.jpa.hibernate.naming.implicit-strategy=org.springframework.boot.orm.jpa.hibernate.SpringImplicitNamingStrategy
logging.level.hibernate=trace
spring.datasource.hikari.data-source-properties.useUnicode=true
spring.datasource.hikari.data-source-properties.characterEncoding=UTF-8
```

The environment variable is overriding the default value of the mariadb URL inside the application.properties file.

Actually, when only the database is running and i use the localhost property inside my springboot application, i am able to connect to it. When i dockerize my springboot application and i try to use the service-name users-db it is not able anymore.

Here's the output from docker:

```
java.sql.SQLNonTransientConnectionException: Could not connect to address=(host=users-db)(port=3306)(type=master) : Socket fail to connect to host:users-db, port:3306. Connection refused

at org.mariadb.jdbc.internal.util.exceptions.ExceptionFactory.createException(ExceptionFactory.java:73) ~[mariadb-java-client-2.7.4.jar!/:na]

at org.mariadb.jdbc.internal.util.exceptions.ExceptionFactory.create(ExceptionFactory.java:197) ~[mariadb-java-client-2.7.4.jar!/:na]

at org.mariadb.jdbc.internal.protocol.AbstractConnectProtocol.connectWithoutProxy(AbstractConnectProtocol.java:1394) ~[mariadb-java-client-2.7.4.jar!/:na]

at org.mariadb.jdbc.internal.util.Utils.retrieveProxy(Utils.java:635) ~[mariadb-java-client-2.7.4.jar!/:na]

at org.mariadb.jdbc.MariaDbConnection.newConnection(MariaDbConnection.java:150) ~[mariadb-java-client-2.7.4.jar!/:na]

at org.mariadb.jdbc.Driver.connect(Driver.java:89) ~[mariadb-java-client-2.7.4.jar!/:na]
```

Does anybody have an idea about what the issue is?

Comment: Were you able to find solution, even i am able to run without docker. But when i am running container it is throwing network connection error